# Значение слова обкуренный

Tags: значение-слов

Лес, не обкуренный зимой. (Твардовский) Как это понять?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Твардовский вообще словами не бросался... За этим эпитетом (или что оно там) должен стоять какой-то емкий образ. Но без контекста понять трудно. Сейчас посмотрю, откуда это.

А, ну так это ж Теркин...

```
Не заваленный кругом;
Блиндажами не изрытый,
Не обкуренный зимой,
Ни своими не обжитый,
Ни чужими под землей
```

Здесь все понятно. Зимой военный лес "обкуривается" землянками.
Само слово "обкуривать" обычно означает *приводить в естественное или рабочее сосотояние методом "курения" - т.е. с помощью дыма*. Обычно это курительная трубка или, скажем, плодовые деревья - в целях борьбы с вредителями. 
Лес, понятно, направленно не обкуривают - во всяком случае в таких масштабах, но Твардовский явно имел в виду дым от печек в землянках.

Comment: Плодовые  деревья  окуривали,  трубку  обкуривали.

Answer (score 1):

Рискну предположить, что  данном случае это метафора. "Не обкуренный зимой" это, может быть,  значит, зима его еще не заснежила.

Comment: Лирический герой описывает лес своего детства и сравнивает его с лесом военным - что может тут значить информация о незаснеженном  лесе?! 

Да и не было помехи  
Взять и вспомнить наугад  
Старый лес, куда в орехи  
Я ходил с толпой ребят.  
Лес - ни пулей, ни осколком  
Не пораненный ничуть,  
Не порубленный без толку,  
Без порядку как-нибудь;  
Не корчеванный фугасом,  
Не поваленный огнем,  
Хламом гильз, жестянок, касок  
Не заваленный кругом;  
Блиндажами не изрытый,  
Не обкуренный зимой,  
Ни своими не обжитый,  
Ни чужими под землей.

Answer (score 1):

Тут явно не опавшая листва имеется в виду. Да и на землянки тоже не похоже.  Во-первых; летом тоже и землянки; и костры будут. Да и в мирное время, костры в лесу вполне возможны. А во-вторых; тут бои с применением артиллерии шли, кому какое дело до костров?

Для того чтобы понять описываемую картину представьте зимний лес.

> Под голубыми небесами
> Великолепными коврами,
> Блестя на солнце, снег лежит;
> Прозрачный лес один чернеет,
> И ель сквозь иней зеленеет,
> И речка подо льдом блестит.

А теперь попробуйте найти то, чего в зимнем лесу после боя не будет. Снега. Он или расстает и станет льдом, или почернеет от копоти сажи и крови. Лес будет не белый с чёрным, а только одна чернота, будто обкуренная изба или баня по чёрному. Летом листья и трава всё равно бы красок своих добавили, поэтому упоминание о зиме тут вовсе не лишнее. Думаю именно эту картину и имел в виду Твардовский.

Comment: Не стыкуется.
Во-первых, снег никуда не денется. Снег был даже в разрушенном Сталинграде. Откуда вы взяли про сплошную черноту - ума не приложу.
Далее. Артиллерия по залесенным участкам обычно не работала. Там целей нет, а что есть - то не видно.   

М наконец.Летом на войне землянки не строили (кроме штабных) - не до того было. А где строили - там не топили, обходились кострами. И летом гарь от костра (а хоть бы и землянки) не так заметна.

Comment: 1. Снег будет, но будет чёрным, по крайней мере, пока новый не выпадет.

2. Для обкуривания какая разница от костра в землянке дым или от костра на открытом воздухе?

3. Фугас в тексте Твардовского может быть конечно и минами, но артиллерия тоже вероятна.

4. Сорокапятки работали и в лесу.

Comment: 1. Нет. Он будет белым. Максимум - сероватым. Гарь в значительных образуется только от сего-то горящего, маскимым - от выстрела, не от снаряда. 
2. А Вы как думаете? 
3. Фугас у Твардовского ***корчует***. Не обкуривает. Что логично.
4. В лесу это - "из лесу" или "по лесу"?

ЗЫ Вы простите, в каком звании будете? Не пробовали поинтересоваться значением терминов "фугас", "мина" и "артиллерия"? Что вы чему тут противопоставляете?

Comment: Увлекательное расследование.  
"У леса на опушке  
Жила зима в избушке,  
Она снежки солила  
В березовой кадушке"

Comment: Я  думаю,  что  это  диалектное  слово.  Ходить  "в  орехи" тоже, вероятно,  диалектизм.  Может  в  смоленских  говорах  был  какой-то  свой  нюанс  слова  "обкуренный".